# How hot is it on the slopes of an erupting volcano?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was watching The Return of the King and just after Frodo and Sam destroy the One Ring, they run out of the mountain and hide on top of a rock as the volcano erupts and lava flows past them. Is this actually feasible or would they have been roasting alive?

Here's an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Spoiler alert...

Comment: thats gandolf on the eagle and not frodo and sam.

Comment: @guru correct, Sam and Frodo are on the rock.

Comment: its not possible to say without actual calculation.it doens't require physics though to say that it is going to be uncomfortably hot. stone is not a very good conductor of heat though so at least it doesn't appear ridiculous. not as unbelievable though as star wars - where spacecrafts make sound in space and light from laser weaponry travels so slowly that it can actually be seen moving from the gun to the target!

Comment: Some calculations can be found at http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136733/26969 - more related to radiated heat but you get the idea.